How to get Named Attributes in Geometry Nodes Modifier in Python
How to get Named Attributes used in Geometry Nodes Modifier via API?
I want to get a list represented by strings

def get_attrs_list(md):
    if not md.node_group: return None
    return [..]

# >>>> [("Read", "position"), ("Read", "sharp_face")]


I don't know if there's a dedicated api feature for that, but iterating over "Store Named Attribute" for writes and "Named Attribute" for reads seems to be a reasonable option. Though I think you would have to do it recursively so would also involve custom groups...

That kind of stuff is gonna be inherently folded into the Object/ObjectData API, since the attributes are tied to the object itself. If you want to get those values it's fairly straightforward. I'm not sure if the node group itself has access to that data aside from what Markus just described.

@MarkusvonBroady Jakemoyo Hi guys could anyone of you be so kind and add an answer for this? I will upvote it :)
